# multiple shell command execution failed

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to execute two shell command at the same time in vim. So i use `|` like below

```
   :!ls|!pwd
```

Its Returns the following error

> E34: No previous command

But what happen ls output is forward to second command, because of the piping.
What this is the solution to solve this problem, How to execute two shell commands like this, to execute inside of vim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [help](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#E34) (`:h E34`)

> Any '!' in {cmd} is replaced with the previous external command

And further in the [help](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#:bar) (`:h :bar`)

> These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be
>   followed by another Vim command:
>
> [various other]
>
> :[range]!
>
> [...]
>
> To be able to use another command anyway, use the ":execute" command.

So if you want to execute 2 shell commands in a row, you need to do this:

```
:exe "!ls" | exe "!pwd"
```

Comment: But what about other commands start with !. Like `!shell` . You said           **Any '!' in {cmd} is replaced with the previous external command**. If i put '!shell' in ex -mode it will open terminal, How its replaced with external commands

Comment: In `:[range]! cmd` `!` is not part of the command. so it only applies, if the `!` comes later in the commandline

Comment: Great @Christian Brabandt . Nice explanations Thanks