# How do I compound multiple autocmds for tmux window renaming?

Tags: autocmd, tmux

I have these automcmds that work nicely for renaming tmux windows with the current filename ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29693196/140872)):

```
autocmd BufEnter * call system("tmux rename-window " . expand("%:t"))
autocmd VimLeave * call system("tmux rename-window bash")
```

I also want to add an additional lines to also change the colour of the window name, with something like this:

```
tmux set -a window-status-current-style "fg=#{@vimfile}"
```

How do I add the additional tmux command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple shell command execution failed](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10155/multiple-shell-command-execution-failed)

Comment: @Biggybi: No, it doesn't, but the answer below does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's not a problem to have multiple `autocmd` for the same event. Moreover, they are guaranteed to execute in the very same order. So you can write it this way:

```
augroup tmux | au!
autocmd BufEnter * call system("tmux rename-window " . expand("%:t"))
autocmd BufEnter * !tmux set -a window-status-current-style "fg=\#{@vimfile}"
augroup end
```

- the first command has to use `expand()` (and so `system()`) not to fail on empty file/buffer name;
- the second command has an extra backslash `\#` because of the Vim's command-line parser;

Note however that in this case you spawn tmux process twice (as well as shell process) per each BufEnter which is suboptimal.

Instead of this, you can use a semicolon to pass multiple tmux commands per a single invocation. It's also possible to take care of an empty file name like this:

```
augroup tmux | au!
autocmd BufEnter * call system(printf('tmux rename-window %s\;
    \ set -a window-status-current-style "fg=#{@vimfile}"',
    \ empty(@%) ? 'Noname' : fnamemodify(@%, ':t')))
augroup end
```

(Yet another backslash `\;` is needed for the shell's parser).

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working and I get some sort of message on startup saying 
`:!tmux rename-window init.vim\; set -a window-status-current-style "fg=#{@vimfile}"

Press ENTER or type command to continue`
I am using neovim v0.5.1 if that makes any difference here.

Comment: I also get this error message when starting with no file:
`Error detected while processing BufEnter Autocommands for "*":
E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h": !tmux rename-window %:t\; set -a window-status-current-style "fg=\#{@vimfile}"`

Comment: @paradroid Indeed. File name modifiers do not like empty names when used on the cmdline (not as an expression). I revised the answer.